# Need help on c#

Tags: c#

I have recently started to learn c# and Im trying to make something like trivia, i have created 3 closed questions(with answers 0-3), and now Im trying to create an open question but i don't know how to make it open, how to make the user enter an answer and how to check if its true or false.
any help will be greatfull!

this is my code:

```
using FirstProject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FirstProject{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            String[] q1a = { "Blue", "Black", "Red", "Green" };
            QuestionA q1 = new QuestionA("What is the color of a tomato?",q1a,2);

            String[] q2a = { "10", "25", "125", "2.5" };
            QuestionA q2 = new QuestionA("how much is 5X5", q2a, 1);

            String[] q3a = { "2", "5", "4", "10" };
            QuestionA q3 = new QuestionA("how many eyes do i have?", q3a, 0);

            List<QuestionA> QL = new List<QuestionA>() { q1, q2, q3, q4 };
            int CorrectA = 0;
            int TotalQ = QL.Count;
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            while (QL.Count > 0)
            {
                int RM = Rnd.Next(0, QL.Count);
                Boolean Answer = QL[RM].PrintQuestion();
                if (Answer) CorrectA++;
                QL.RemoveAt(RM);

            }
            //Console.WriteLine(TotalQ);
            Double GrD = ((Double)CorrectA / (Double)TotalQ) * 100;
            if (GrD < 56)
                Console.WriteLine("You Have failed, Your Grade is:" + GrD);
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats u Passed the test with a grade of:" + GrD);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FirstProject
{
    class QuestionA
    {
        public String question;
        public String[] answers;
        public int correct;
        public QuestionA(String question, String[] answers, int correct)
        {
            this.question = question;
            this.answers = answers;
            this.correct = correct;
        }
        public Boolean PrintQuestion()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plz type the right answer(0-3)");
            Console.WriteLine("Q:" + this.question);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ":" + this.answers[i]);
            }
            return this.CheckAnswer();
        }
        public Boolean CheckAnswer()
        {
            int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (this.correct == answer)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Thx a lot with any help!

Comment: Hi Cactus and welcome! Glad to hear you are learning C# as it's a great language. This question is rather open ended though, can you please add what you are hoping to do, at least as a verbal description, in greater detail? Also, anything you have tried so far. The more specific you are, the more likely you are to get meaningful answers back.

Comment: Hi, what kind of question and answer where you thinking of  ? You could check if the answer (as string) contains the keyword of the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Nik, so i wanna make and open question, i will give u and example:
The question: "what is the color of the sky's at night?"
and i want the user will enter the answer on Console.readLine(), and then i will run my check answer func to check if its correct or not.
I havent tried anything tey, bcuz i cant find anything online that helps me understand how it works, maybe im not searching the right keywords...

Comment: you could define an array with possible answers, and then when the user enters the answer you can check how many of the words in the correct_answers array match and decide if it's correct or no

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1425/ may help you to rethink "i wanna make and open question" part... (https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1425:_Tasks if the picture alone is not enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple first approach would be to declare keywords expected in the answer and to check if the user answer contains any/some/all of the expected keywords.

The new type of question would have to created like this:

```
String[] q4a = { "black" };
QuestionOpen q4 = new QuestionOpen("what is the color of the sky's at night?", q4a);
```

with the QuestionOpen like this :

```
class QuestionOpen
{
    public String question;
    public String[] correctKeyWords;
    public QuestionOpen(String question, String[] correctKeyWords)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctKeyWords = correctKeyWords;
    }
    public Boolean PrintQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plz type your answer");
        Console.WriteLine("Q:" + this.question);
        return this.CheckAnswer();
    }
    public Boolean CheckAnswer()
    {
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        bool isAnswerCorrect = false;
        foreach( string keyWord in this.correctKeyWords)
        {
            if (answer.Contains(keyWord))
            {
                isAnswerCorrect = true;
                //You could have a counter and check if a percentage of the keyword are in the answer
            }
            else
            {
                //Nothing do do
            }
        }
        return isAnswerCorrect;
    }
}
```

A good way to check the keywords instead of the "contains" used here would be a fuzzy search but it isn't the best way to start c# imo as it might not be easy/fun to do.

Let me know if you have any question regarding this (I tried not to change to much code as to not make it confusing).

Ps: A nice way to integrate the new type of question into your list would be to declare an interface. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface (It's basically a way to declare the methods/property that the object implementing the interface must have).

usage :

```
List<IQuestion> QL = new List<IQuestion>() { q1, q2, q3, q4};
        int CorrectA = 0;
        int TotalQ = QL.Count;
        Random Rnd = new Random();
        while (QL.Count > 0)
        {
            int RM = Rnd.Next(0, QL.Count);
            Boolean Answer = QL[RM].PrintQuestion();
            if (Answer) CorrectA++;
            QL.RemoveAt(RM);
        }
```

Comment: wow man, thx a lot, have a good one!
i would love to get any suggestions on how and where to start learning c#

Comment: It seems to me that the best way is what you are doing (find a fun project and just start working on it :) ). This way you will keep on having new questions and meet new problems making you learn more. Once you have a few questions in your trivia you could make it so that the questions are in a textfile so you don't have to code to add a new question for exemple.

Comment: ok, ty, and one more thing, about that row:
```List<IQuestion> QL = new List<IQuestion>() { q1, q2, q3, q4};
```
i cannot insert those 2 type of questions on the same list, if im doing:
```List<QuestionA> QL = new List<IQuestion>() { q1, q2, q3, q4};
```
the q4 is not convertable to questionA from questionOpen.
and elsewhere.
so do u know how can i solve it so it works in one list?

Comment: No problem, that was why I mentionned declaring an Interface (I didn't post the code for the Interface because I thought it might be interesting for you to check it). Check the link in my post about interface and try to make it (it is a new File (interface) with about three lines of code). If you can't figure it out, just reply to my comment (with @Ostas so I get a notification) and I will post the interface.

Comment: i didnt really understood how to work with the interface on my work.
any chance u can help me?

Comment: It isn't the easiest concept. Check this: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-interface  IPen in the first exemple would be IQuestion.

Comment: Ty I have tried and succeed, any idea on how i can keep develop the trivia game?

Comment: As I mentionned, you could read the questions from a textfile/csv, you could have a score/scoreboard. You could also create a visual interface instead of using the console. Have fun :)